# Core and modules upgrade

Tags: 7, upgrading

I want to upgrade my site from Drupal 6 to the latest version of Drupal 7. Currently I have version Drupal 6.21 for my site and there are other releases available 6.22 - 6.29 so I need to upgrade first to 6.29 or I can directly upgrade to Drupal 6.37 which is the latest version in Drupal 6? Also after having latest Drupal 6 version can I then upgrade directly to 7.41 or I need to do it in steps like 1-4?

Is it necessary to update core and modules first to the latest version of Drupal 6, before upgrading to Drupal 7, or can I directly upgrade to Drupal 7? I read a few articles on this, but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't skip versions when you upgrade. For instance you cant go from 6.0 to 6.2 in one step. You also can't upgrade directly from 6.0 or 6.1 to Drupal 7. You have to have your Drupal 6 installation at the latest level.

Comment: Currently I have version Drupal 6.21 for my site and there are other releases available 6.22 - 6.29 so I need to upgrade first to 6.29 or I can directly upgrade to Drupal 6.37 which is the latest version in Drupal 6?

Also after having latest Drupal 6 version then I can upgrade directly to 7.41 or I need to do it in steps like 1-4?

Comment: yes you will go directly to drupal 6.37(latest version)

Comment: Also after having latest Drupal 6 version then I can upgrade directly to 7.41 or I need to do it in steps like 1-4?

Comment: No need to go step by step you just go one step and skip in between steps and move to 7.41